# 3 table addition and subtraction

Tags: mysql, sum, subtraction

I have three tables:

[image: Description of tablo1 and tablo2 and tablo3]

I want to group all the results according to Table 3 collection operation and year.

**Here is an example of what I want:**

**tablo1**
2017 -> 2100(alacak)

**tablo2**
2017 -> 600(borc)

- 2100(alacak) - 600(borc) = 1600(result)

**tablo3**
2017 -> 600(gider)

- **1600(result) - 600(gider) = 1000(final)**

**I tried a code like this:**

```
SELECT tablo1.year, (SUM(tablo1.alacak)-SUM(tablo2.borc)-SUM(tablo3.gider)) AS result
FROM
    tablo1 JOIN tablo2 ON tablo1.alacak = tablo2.borc        
    LEFT JOIN giderler ON tablo1.alacak = tablo3.gider
    GROUP BY tablo1.year DESC;
```

But it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier of you could add the text of that image to the post itself. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) to see why. (This post is about code, but a lot of points also apply here.)

Comment: Your JOIN conditions seems incorrect. Why you are filtering records using `ON tablo1.alacak = tablo2.borc`? Don't you need to do that on `year` fields?

Comment: @Ivar I reinstalled

Comment: @TuğcaEker SELECT tablo1.year, (SUM(tablo1.alacak)-SUM(tablo2.borc)-SUM(tablo3.gider)) AS sonuc
    FROM
        tablo1 JOIN tablo2 ON tablo1.year = tablo2.year        
        LEFT JOIN giderler ON tablo1.year = tablo3.year
        GROUP BY tablo1.year DESC;

Comment: @TuğcaEker I tried this way but I can not get the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e79558/9) what you want???

```
select year,
 (select sum(alacak) quantity 
      from table1 
    where table1.year = t3.year) 
    -
 (select sum(borc) quantity
    from table2 
   where table2.year = t3.year)
   - 
 (select sum(gider) quantity 
    from table3
   where table3.year = t3.year) as result
   from table3 t3
   group by year;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error about this line. 
from table3
   where table3.year = t3.year) as result
   from table3 t3

Comment: I get such a result.
year -> 2017   result -> NULL